# Merge column name in .dat file and convert it into a spark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am giving `sample.dat` data and `.dml`

Content in `.dat` file:

```
101|US|Ram
102|INDIA|Shyam
103|JAPAN|Geeta
```

Sample `.dml` file:

```
record
string("|") ID;
string("|") Country;
string("\n") Name;
end;
```

In my `.dat` file column name is not there I want to supply column name (`.dml` file)and append that column name in my `.dat` file and convert into **spark dataframe**.

I tried the code below:

```
dataset = "my_file_name.dat"
dataFile = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter",'|').option("header","false").load(dataset)
        
dataFile = dataFile.toDF("COL1","COL2","COL3")
dataFile.show()
```

This is working but here manually I give column name but I want to supply column name from a `.dml` file as mentioned above.

Now I tried below code in python 3.6

```
with open ("src.dml") as fp:
    next (fp)
    cols = []
    row = fp.readline().strip()
    while not row.startswith('end;'):
        row = fp.readline().strip()
        col = row.split(maxsplit=1).strip(';')
        cols.append(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract column from your `dml` file, you can use:

```
# walrus operator, Python>=3.8
with open('data.dml') as fp:
    next(fp)  # skip first row
    cols = []
    while not (row := fp.readline().strip()).startswith('end;'):
        col = row.split(maxsplit=1)[1].strip(';')
        cols.append(col)
```

Output:

```
>>> cols
['ID', 'Country', 'Name']
```

**Update**: for Python<3.8, you can use:

```
with open('data.dml') as fp:
    cols = []
    for row in fp:
        row = row.strip()
        if row.startswith('record'):
            is_record = True
        elif row.startswith('end'):
            is_record = False
        elif is_record:
            col = row.split(maxsplit=1)[-1].strip(';')
            cols.append(col)
```

After, you can do:

```
dataFile = (spark.read.format("csv")
                 .option("delimiter",'|').option("header","false")
                 .load('data.dat').toDF(*cols))
```

Output:

```
>>> dataFile.show()
+---+-------+-----+
| ID|Country| Name|
+---+-------+-----+
|101|     US|  Ram|
|102|  INDIA|Shyam|
|103|  JAPAN|Geeta|
+---+-------+-----+
```

To write to your file, do:

```
dataFile.toPandas().to_csv('data.csv', index=False, sep='|')
```

Content of `data.csv` is now:

```
ID|Country|Name
101|US|Ram
102|INDIA|Shyam
103|JAPAN|Geeta
```

Comment: Okay, when i applied the same logic in my original data I m getting error : list index out out of range

Comment: Can you provide a full dml file, please?

Comment: I tried the logic which you gave in python 3.6 version

Comment: I updated my answer to be usable with Python 3.6. Can you check it please?

Comment: How can I append in my .dat file here??